# Discovered - currently not indexed - N/A Last Crawl Date in Search Console

Tags: google-search-console

I am facing an issue, some of my blogs are giving this return Discovered - currently not indexed, I tried to link with them but still, the last crawl date is showing N/A. I started the Validation process also but Google Bot is not crawling and when I live inspect this URL, it shows the [image]URL Can be indexed.

Please Guide!

Comment: Is that the full screen?  I see a different layout.  If you go to Pages (left hand menu) and scroll down to **Why pages aren't indexed**.  Does that help ?

Comment: No, I just cut the another part.

Comment: There's really nothing we can do to help since this depends on your content and Google's crawling que and algorithm. Please review the questions marked as a duplicate and Google's help guide [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7440203?hl=en).